# VF page Not executing

Tags: visualforce, javascript, mobile

I have a JS button that works fine in Salesforce Classic:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 
if(
  '{!JSENCODE(TEXT(Account.Partner_Type__c ))}' == 'Dealer')
   { 
   var retId; 
   retId = sforce.apex.execute("CallABCWebServiceAccountUpdate", 
   "ABCWebServiceAccountUpdate", {id:'{!Account.Id}'}); 

   alert("The Dealer information that renders on the ABC.com Search result 
   page has been updated");
   }

  else if(
  '{!JSENCODE(TEXT(Account.Partner_Type__c ))}' ==  'Distributor') 
   { 

  var retId; 
  retId = sforce.apex.execute("CallABCWebServiceAccountUpdate", 
  "ABCWebServiceAccountUpdate", {id:'{!Account.Id}'}); 

  alert("The Distributor information that renders on the ABC.com Search result page has been updated");
  }
  else
  { 
  alert("You can only UPDATE the Database with information from Active Dealer, Trexpro, or Non Trex Pro Accounts"); 
}
```

But I have been informed that this process needs to be available on a mobile device.

So I create a VF page.  Here is a sample of it:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:includeScript value="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js"/>
<script>
sforce.connection.sessionId='{!GETSESSIONID()}';

if(
'{!Account.Partner_Type__c }' == 'Dealer' )
 { 
   var retId; 
   retId = sforce.apex.execute("CallABCWebServiceAccountUpdate", 
   "ABCWebServiceAccountUpdate", {id:'{!Account.Id}'}); 
 }
```

I created a quick action and associated the VF page to it.
So when I select the quick action on the mobile device it opens a new window and has a Cancel and Save(grey) button. So i removed the alerts thinking they were the issue.  But in the developer console I can see that the Web service class is never executed. Help with the VF page is appreciated.
Thanks
M

Comment: Include this too <script src="/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: much easier to maintain would be to perform the logic in Visualforce page's controller

Comment: Raul,  are you suggesting that in my Class I add additional logic?       
    @future(Callout=true)<br/>
    static void TrexWebServiceAccountUpdateAsync(String id)   {
        System.debug(id);   
       accounts = [SELECT id,Partner_Type__c FROM Account WHERE id =:id];  
                 if(id != null )  
                   {  
                   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();  
                   Http http = new Http();  
                   req.setMethod('GET');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" >
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/36.0/apex.js"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    function testRemote(){
        sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
        try {
          var id = sforce.apex.execute("HelperClass","getContactId",{});
                alert('id is: '+id);
        } catch(e) {
          alert('Exception'+e)
        }

        }

 </script>

 <div>  
    <button onclick="testRemote();">
      Remote
    </button>
  </div>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Avijit, Can the If statements reside within the Try Catch?

Comment: Avijit, to clarify your example.  I will have a quick action button that will call the VF page which will open a new page where the user will have to click another button?  Just want to make sure I am understand this correctly.  Thanks

Comment: Use try catch to see if any error is there and well as in your VF page  apex.js was not included

Comment: Avijit.  There does not appear to be any errors and the call is made to the web service.   I have a confirmation alert pop up.  Its's just an odd layout to show the save button when there is no 'Save' activity being performed.  Ideally after the user closes the alert the child page would close and go back to the parent account.  Thanks